# Textbook errata for Linear Algebra: Ideas and Application by Richard C. Penney

Tags: linear-algebra

I think there's a mistake at the end of the proof for Theorem 2.16 on page 138: instead of "Thus, **AX** = **B** is solvable for **B** in $\mathbb{R}^m$ it states "Thus, **AX** = **B** is solvable for **B** in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Just something I noticed. Can somebody make sure for me just so I know I'm not going crazy?

[image]

Comment: Nope, the book is right.

Comment: At the bottom of the page?  AX = B is solvable for all B in R^n...what seems different than the original assertion.

Comment: Ah, I had misread your claim! Yes, that $\mathbb{R}^n$ should be an $\mathbb{R}^m$. I thought you wanted to replace the $\mathbb{R}^m$ by an $\mathbb{R}^n$ in Theorem 2.16.